# .NET or Mono / C# Dispatch copy file job to SAN

Tags: c#, .net, mono, io, san

What do you think is the best approach to solve this issue. I have a C# application that receives a XML list of files. Based off this XML list many files (~10 megabyte size) get copied from one folder on our local SAN to another folder on the same local SAN. But all those file copies transfer via the C# Windows App that is actually doing the file copying. This takes 20 minutes per job. Any good ideas on how to dispatch a set of copy instructions to the SAN via C# but not have the local box be involved in the transfer?

Does the Mono codebase offer a way to SSH into a box and execute commands? This is my only idea so far to greatly reduce the execution time these jobs take.

**UPDATE**
The SAN is the Clariion NS 480
http://www.tech.proact.co.uk/emc/emc_celerra_ns-480_nas.htm
I assume this is a Linux or Unix operating system inside.
Trying to find some better technical specs.

Comment: The SAN runs a unix derivative?

Comment: Building on Ritch's comment, you'll need to provide more details about your SAN to get a really good solution.

Comment: Does your SAN appear as different disks to you? does anything see it as one disk? If nothing sees it as one drive, you will always have to copy the whole file. If you can tell the SAN host itself to copy it then you might get some speed up.  Could this xml be compressed before sending?

Comment: http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx might help you a little

Answer (score 0):

You could run a process on the SAN that executes a specific script every x minutes. Create that script from your c# application.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would use SSH from the C# application in such a situation to issue the needed copy commands BUT from the link you posted none of the protocols listed supports such a mechanism... neither SSH not TELNET (which I would NOT recommend for security reasons) is listed as a supported protocol... without such a protocol your only option is to have your local machine involved in the copy process... I highly recommend checking back with the vendor about SSH support...